# How to access parent element in Scala XML

Tags: xml, scala

The `scala.xml` package represents XML with nodes of a labelled tree. But is this tree unidirectional in Scala 2.7, as there seems to be no way to access the `Elem` parent of a given `Elem`? The same seems to apply for parent `Document`. For example, in XOM you have `getParent` and `getDocument` accessors to navigate towards the root of the tree. Can this be done with Scala's XML API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned by others, there are no parent links to make them efficient immutable structures. For example:

```
scala> val a = <parent><children>me</children></parent>
a: scala.xml.Elem = <parent><children>me</children></parent>

scala> val b = a.child(0)
b: scala.xml.Node = <children>me</children>

scala> val c = <newparent>{b}</newparent>
c: scala.xml.Elem = <newparent><children>me</children></newparent>

scala> a
res0: scala.xml.Elem = <parent><children>me</children></parent>

scala> b
res1: scala.xml.Node = <children>me</children>

scala> c
res3: scala.xml.Elem = <newparent><children>me</children></newparent>
```

No data structure was copied. The node pointed to by `b` is the very same node pointed to by both `a` and `c`. If it had to point to a parent, then you'd have to make a copy of it when you used it in `c`.

To navigate in that data structure the way you want, you need what is called a Purely Applicative XML Cursor.

Answer (score 3):

> But is this tree unidirectional in Scala?

Yes. Due to the approach to immutability in scala.xml, nodes don't know their parent.

Answer (score 1):

It is unidirectional, so nodes are unaware of their parent.

You might be able to solve your problem by converting to a DOM. There doesn't seem to be anything in the standard library for this, but I found [this thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2884) on the subject which might be useful.