# Is there a way to get a "reverse" XPath in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

If I have a DOM, is it possible to get the reverse XPath of an element? For example, if I have :

```
<start>
  <nodes>
    <node>
      <name>Whatever</name>
    </node>
    <node>
      <name>Whatever 2</name>
    </node>
  </nodes>
</start>
```

If for example, I have a reference to the node with the name `Whatever 2`, is it possible to get back `/start/nodes/node/name[. = "Whatever 2"]`?

Comment: Note that there are multiple XPath expression for many (possibly all) nodes. That may be fine for you, but that depends on what you need to do.

Comment: I would be ok even with something more generic, as `/start/nodes/node`

Comment: Note that if you're using Scala's built-in XML support it's only giving you something _DOM-like_. There are [no parent links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582244/how-to-access-parent-element-in-scala-xml), for example, which makes what you describe a little tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very simple approach to walking up the tree using the Java DOM API in the Scala REPL:

First we import the relevant packages and set up our document builder and source:

```
scala> import org.w3c.dom._
import org.w3c.dom._

scala> import javax.xml.parsers._
import javax.xml.parsers._

scala> val factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
factory: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = ...

scala> val builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder()
builder: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder = ...

scala> val source = new org.xml.sax.InputSource()
source: org.xml.sax.InputSource = org.xml.sax.InputSource@7ecec7c6
```

Now to parse the example document:

```
scala> val content = """<start>
             <nodes>
               <node><name>Whatever</name></node>
               <node><name>Whatever 2</name></node>
             </nodes>
           </start>"""
content: java.lang.String = ...

scala> source.setCharacterStream(new java.io.StringReader(content))

scala> val document = builder.parse(source)
document: org.w3c.dom.Document = [#document: null]
```

This is a very simple function that recursively walks up the DOM to the document root:

```
scala> def path: Node => String = {
     |   case document: Document => ""
     |   case node => path(node.getParentNode) + "/" + node.getNodeName
     | }
path: org.w3c.dom.Node => String
```

And we pick the second `<name>` node to test:

```
scala> val node = document.getElementsByTagName("name").item(1)
node: org.w3c.dom.Node = [name: null]
```

We get what we expect:

```
scala> path(node)
res1: String = /start/nodes/node/name
```

It wouldn't be hard to tweak the `path` function to avoid explicit recursion or to gather more information as it walks up the tree—for example indicating position when necessary to avoid ambiguity:

```
scala> def path(element: Element) = {
     |   def sameName(f: Node => Node)(n: Node) =
     |     Stream.iterate(n)(f).tail.takeWhile(_ != null).filter(
     |       _.getNodeName == n.getNodeName
     |     ).toList
     |   val preceding = sameName(_.getPreviousSibling) _
     |   val following = sameName(_.getNextSibling) _
     |   "/" + Stream.iterate[Node](element)(_.getParentNode).map {
     |     case _: Document => None
     |     case e: Element => Some { (preceding(e), following(e)) match {
     |       case (Nil, Nil) => e.getTagName
     |       case (els, _)   => e.getTagName + "[" + (els.size + 1) + "]"
     |     }}
     |   }.takeWhile(_.isDefined).map(_.get).reverse.mkString("/")
     | }
path: (element: org.w3c.dom.Element)java.lang.String
```

Note that I've changed the type slightly to make it clear that this will only give us a valid XPath path for elements. We can test:

```
scala> path(node.asInstanceOf[Element])
res13: java.lang.String = /start/nodes/node[2]/name
```

This is again what we expect.

Comment: Thank you Travis for a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, if all you have is a `scala.xml.Node`, you're not going to achieve your goal without spending a ridiculous amount of time and space.

However, if you're willing to make your callers jump through a few hoops, and you find the idea of dropping down to Java distasteful, you could do worse than to try a [zipper](http://szeiger.de/blog/2009/12/27/a-zipper-for-scala-xml/).

Also see Daniel Spiewak's [implementation](http://anti-xml.org/zippers.html) in Anti-XML (likely to replace Scala's built-in XML support someday)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a function like path(Node):XPath? Unfortunately this is not possible to do efficiently with scala.xml as nodes have no parent reference. Options are:
1) Search the tree and properly id when you have found the right node.
2) Use another XML lib (scala or java) that supports parent refs...anti-xml, etc

Comment: I will accept solutions using Java libs as well, as they are directly useable from Scala.